# want if dates selected are in between textbox2 dates and textbox3 dates then textbox1.text="sumit" else textbox1.text="No dates"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i have three textboxes in my vb.net webform ..

Textbox1.text="Sumit"

Textbox2.text="4-Dec-2010"

Textbox3.text="1-Jan-2011"

I want if dates selected are in between textbox2 dates and textbox3 dates then textbox1.text="sumit" else textbox1.text="No dates"

Comment: You need to do two things. You have to accept answers for your questions. 2nd thing is to re-write your question in a more meaningful manner, because it is a bit unclear what is wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your TextChanged method of your textboxes. Set Textbox1.Text = CheckDates().

```
Function CheckDates
    'Checks to make sure dates were entered'
    If Not IsDate(Textbox2.text) or Not IsDate(Textbox3.text) Then
        Return "No Dates"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If CType(Textbox2.text,Date) >= #12/4/2010# and CType(Textbox3.text,Date) <= #1/1/2011# then
        Return "Submit"
    Else
        Return "No Dates"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: If you're going to be writing code, it's important that you learn the fundamentals. For Textbox2 and Textbox3, add the following line in the TextChanged event, Textbox1.text = CheckDates

Comment: Furthermore, I see you've posted a lot of questions and not marked any answers accepted. If you're going to solicit the help of members of this site, be kind enough to mark answers when they're helpful.